# Java JDBC rowset to tocollection() method use

Tags: java, jdbc, collections

This is Java 8, Oracle JVM on Windows/Linux and using latest JDBC Java 8 compatible driver for MS-SQL (if it makes any difference).

I want to convert/cast/move data from a JDBC `RowSet` such as a `CachedRowSet` using the `toCollection()` method into a `Collection` of complete rows. This would allow me to use `stream()` and lambda to process the row set inside my Java program.

The single column `toCollection("colname")` method works fine for me.

I would like to know how to convert from JDBC row set into a collection containing *all columns* of the row set.
I searched for examples but did not find any, any pointers on this will be much appreciated.

Comment: This is exactly what `toCollection()` already does. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I wanted to see example of using toCollection() method to convert CachedRowSet to collection. Not for single column but for the complete row, all columns of the row. So the output is a Collection of Rows where each rows contains all columns individually.

Comment: That's what it does. Read the Javadoc. If you're asking for an off-site resource you're off-topic here, but surely there's an example in the Oracle JDBC Tutorial?  And surely you've made some attempt of your own we can comment on?

Comment: there is nothing in Javadoc that helps me with toCollection() method. I have tried and getting cast exception: com.sun.rowset.internal.Row cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable.

Comment: I am not asking for off-site resource, I wanted to see some examples. I did not realize that web pointers off-site are not permitted.

Comment: nothing in Oracle JDBC tutorial, hence my question: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/cachedrowset.html

Comment: Collection<Vector<SQLData>> c = (Collection<Vector<SQLData>>) crsSqlRs.toCollection(); // tried <?> and without Vector, same errors

Comment: Where did you get `Vector<SQLData>` from? It's not in the Javadoc or the tutorial. The Javadoc doesn't go give any grounds for anything beyond `Vector<?>`. Why don't you just get the `Collection` and *see* what's in it?

Comment: I know what is it in. com.sun.rowset.internal.Row, see my first reply to you. I wanted to see a working code fragment of how to use toCollection();. Clearly you either don't have the answers or you don't want to answer - so why do you bother to type replies that are worthless? Your RTFM replies are of no help.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, you need to use `toCollection()` method, but that returns collection of `com.sun.rowset.internal.Row` which needs to be transformed to work with stream API. See the example:

```
ResultSetMetaData md = rowset.getMetaData();
List<Map<String, Object>> res = new ArrayList<>();
Collection<Row> c = (Collection<Row>) rowset.toCollection();
for(Row row: c) {
    Map<String, Object> m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= md.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        m.put(md.getColumnName(i), row.getColumnObject(i));
    }
    res.add(m);
}
res.stream().forEach(m -> System.out.println(m));
```

Comment: thanks but I get access restriction trying to access the class Row from com.sun.rowset.internal.Row;

Comment: plus it is being defined as internal so I am not sure if it is supported for me to use this class?

Comment: I think its details of realization of the JDBC driver that you are using. With jtds (net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver) of latest version it works fine.

Comment: thanks, looks like I am stuck, wont be able to use this method. It is a pity that Row class is internal.

Comment: Consider not to use method toCollection at all. Anyway, you can construct desired collection by iterating over rowset.next() and mapping results like in example above.

Comment: thank you, yes indeed, this is what I was going to do. At first I wanted to re-use provided library but this method does not seem to be 100% baked for general use. Pity, since method toCollection("colum_name") works very well.

Answer (score 0):

This may help someone else, I don't know.
It turns out my code was actually OK. 
I had to change the IDE Eclipse setting to change the Restricted access messages from default setting of Error to Warning. This change permitted me to use Java Collection of Row (internal Sun class, imported) and to convert the JDBC row set to a Java collection suitable for use in Java 8 streams. I don't know if this is practice is supported or if its even a good practice to use the Sun internal Row class via import com.sun.rowset.internal.*; but the code does run correctly now.

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look at the following snippet:

```
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
HashMap<String,Object> map;
while(rs.next()){
    int numColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
    map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    for (int i=1; i<=numColumns; i++) {
        String colName = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
        if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.ARRAY){
            map.put(colName, rs.getArray(colName));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.BIGINT){
            map.put(colName, rs.getInt(colName));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.BOOLEAN){
            map.put(colName, rs.getBoolean(colName));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.BLOB){
            map.put(colName, rs.getBlob(colName));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.DOUBLE){
            map.put(colName, rs.getDouble(colName)); 
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.FLOAT){
            map.put(colName, rs.getFloat(colName));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.INTEGER){
            map.put(colName, rs.getInt(colName));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.NVARCHAR){
            map.put(colName, rs.getNString(colName));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.VARCHAR){
            map.put(colName, rs.getString(colName));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.TINYINT){
            map.put(colName, rs.getInt(colName));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.SMALLINT){
            map.put(colName, rs.getInt(colName));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.DATE){
            map.put(colName, rs.getDate(colName));
        }
        else if(rsmd.getColumnType(i)==java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP){
            map.put(colName, rs.getTimestamp(colName));   
        }
        else{
            map.put(colName, rs.getObject(colName));
        }
    }
    //do something with the map here..
}
```

Comment: this does not answer my question. I want to know how to use toCollection() method of CachedRowSet to copy all rows, all columns of row set into a Collection containing all rows and all columns.